# Refrigeration of Potatoes au Gratin

Tags: baking

After making Potatoes au Gratin. Before cooking it, I placed it in the refrigerator. How long would it keep in the refrigerator until you are ready to cook it?

Comment: Did you parcook your potatoes?  My limited experience with it (before I knew I had dairy issues) would make me think that cooking it with raw potatoes from a cold state would really suck.  (2 hours and the middle was still crunchy, possibly because I kept checking it every 15 minutes past when the recipe said it should take)

Comment: Related: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/12432/67

Comment: @Joe yep. Trick is to microwave it for about 30 min, then bake.

Comment: @bob1 I reckon the biggest part of that trick is to use a dish that fits in your microwave. The one I use fits but doesn't go round so you can take the chill off the middle but not very well

Comment: Also if you don't precook, any potato that sticks out will go grey

Comment: @scott In addition to Joe's question - if you did pre-cook, did you then cool to room temp or assemble hot/warm. These sorts of things play into food safety considerations.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, if the refrigerator keeps it at no more than 5°C, and if the cream used was still well ahead of its expiration date, keeping it in the fridge for up to 48 hours should be safe.